# Position of a TikZ picture in a page

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a problem with the position of a TikZ picture. I have the following code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={STD$_{medidos}$}, % label x axis
ylabel={STD$_{corregidos}$}, % label y axis
axis lines=left, %set the position of the axes
xmin=0, xmax=599, % set the min and max values of the x-axis
ymin=0, ymax=599, % set the min and max values of the y-axis
title=\color{red}{STD$_{corr.}=\alpha $ STD$_{med.}$+ $\beta$},
clip=false
]
\addplot[only marks] table[row sep=\\]{
        X Y\\
        0 0.01\\
        244.74 244.83\\
        379.52 379.38\\
        552.3 553.63\\
    };
    \addplot table[row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] % compute a linear regression from the
    %input table
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.01\\
        244.74 244.83\\
        379.52 379.38\\
        552.3 553.63\\
    };
 
    \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \caption{Recta de calibrado para la corrección de medidas de $x$CO$_2$} 
     \label{fig:M1}
     \end{figure}
     \end{center}
```

When I try to set it in a page I obtain the following result:

[image]

How can I position this figure just after the text?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You should post a minimal working example, instead of posting just a code snippet.

Comment: Hi, welcome! This doesn't really have anything to with TikZ, but the `figure` environment. A `figure` is a floating environment, so it can move by design. You can try with `\begin{figure}[hb]` instead of just `\begin{figure}`. For (a lot) more information about float positioning, see the four highest voted questions tagged with `floats` and `positioning`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/positioning%2bfloats?tab=Votes

Comment: Thank you for your comments and for your corrections to my question!! Not only am I new to this forum, but I am also new to LaTeX. I'm sorry if this was an elementary question!

Comment: Sometimes it is helpful not to use the figure environment. If you remove the lines \begin{figure} \end{figure}, then the TikZ picture appears immediately. In this case you have to replace \caption{Recta...} by  \captionof{figure}{Recta...}. \captionof comes with \usepackage{caption}.